# JS/jQuery action fired when scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

This question is purely for usability purpose.

I'm sorry if the title of the question is not very clear. It's not about how to fire an action when a page is scrolled to top (not very hard), but about how to fire an action when the user scroll to top and continuously try scrolling more (top).

The scenario is as follow: The page initially loads a list of items via AJAX and render them. If the user try to scroll up more and more and more to top (and don't stop scrolling on the top position), then a "loading newer items" action should be called.

How to make it happens?

Comment: So you want an infinite scroll that works at the top, not just the bottom?

Comment: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

Comment: @Barmar Yes I want such thing. Actually it's just for new items (pretty limited, not infinite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might think the loading more items div is above the top of the window. But what the websites are doing: they create a div on position y = 0px to let's say y = 30px. When they show the page they automaticly scroll to y=30px. So people will see the normal page, now when the user scrolls up (which is of course possible since he is on y=30px) he will see the "Loading more items" div, you can easily check if the "loading more items" div is visible in the current viewport since it is part of the page, and fire the event to load more items if so, in the callback of this function, you can scroll to y=30px again.

Comment: It's very good way but probably not as ideal as "release to refresh" of Tablet/Smartphone.

Comment: You might think that other apps might work differenly, which I thought first too, but after talking with many developers I found out that they all created the function this way :) of course it's possible that there are other solutions as well, but from what I saw, this is "well-known" way to do it.

Comment: By the way, creating the fancy bounceback effects and slide effects is possible with coding in JavaScript :)

Comment: @hiro, forgot to tag your name in comment, so you prob did not get a notification :) anyways if you have more questions about it let me know